# Simplify $\sqrt {9 + 2(1 + \sqrt {3})(1 + \sqrt {7})}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, nested-radicals

Simplify

$\sqrt {9 + 2(1 + \sqrt {3})(1 + \sqrt {7})}$

I know this requires denesting but I don't know how to begin here.

Answer (score 8):

$9 + 2(1 + \sqrt {3})(1 + \sqrt {7})=1^2+(\sqrt3)^2+(\sqrt{7})^2+2\sqrt3+2\sqrt7+2(\sqrt3)(\sqrt7)=(1+\sqrt3+\sqrt7)^2$